# How to handle encrypted column in SQL Server Database in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

We are in the process of encrypting all the SSN columns (had to do it now due to security audit). We already built the DBML and now we have to change it. Can you guys let me know if there is a good way of handling this in LINQ to SQL? We use stored procedures for Insert, Update and Delete but use LINQ to SQL for all our selects (ease of use). Do I have to change the format for those tables with SSN or Is there any other manner we can handle it in LINQ to SQL?

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching long on this topic we have decided to use stored procedures to handle the encrypted column table and use those CRUD stored procedures in LINQ to SQL.

Hope this helps someone.